# The error in copy layer by GDAL

Tags: gdal, file-geodatabase-api

I used GDAL meathod “GDALDataset::CopyLayer” to copy a layer outside the dataset to the dataset in FileGDB. But, the error is "ERROR 1: Failed at creating table for \K2\KCOUPLtemp (Invalid spatial reference.)" worried me.I have searched the GDALAPI and found one CopyLayer parameter that papszOptions is a StringList of name=value options and Options are driver specific. There is a common option to set output layer spatial reference: DST_SRSWKT. The option should be in WKT format.My code is following:

```
    const char* gdbpath = "G:\\GeoMarkData\\K3_1_1.gdb";
    GDALAllRegister();
    CPLSetConfigOption("GDAL_FILENAME_IS_UTF8", "NO");  
    CPLSetConfigOption("SHAPE_ENCODING", "");
    GDALDriver* driver = GetGDALDriverManager()->GetDriverByName("FileGDB");

    if (driver != NULL)
    {
        GDALDataset* ds = (GDALDataset*)GDALOpenEx(gdbpath, GDAL_OF_VECTOR | GDAL_OF_UPDATE, NULL, NULL, NULL);

        if (ds->GetLayerCount() > 0)
        {
            
            vector<string> CopiedName;

            for (int i = 0; i < ds->GetLayerCount(); i++)
            {
                CopiedName.push_back(ds->GetLayer(i)->GetName());
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < CopiedName.size(); i++)
            {

                OGRLayer* old_layer = ds->GetLayerByName(CopiedName.at(i).c_str());
                OGRSpatialReference* oldsp = old_layer->GetSpatialRef();

                char* sp = NULL;
                oldsp->exportToWkt(&sp);
                cout << sp << endl;

                string nametemp = CopiedName.at(i);
                string copyname = nametemp + "temp";
                char** papszOptions = NULL;

                papszOptions = CSLSetNameValue(papszOptions, "DST_SRSWKT", sp);
                papszOptions = CSLSetNameValue(papszOptions, "FEATURE_DATASET", "K2");

                OGRLayer* templayer = ds->CopyLayer(old_layer, copyname.c_str(), papszOptions);
                CSLDestroy(papszOptions);
            }
        }
        GDALClose(ds);
    }
}
```

---

The data is a FileGDB and hava one dataset named “K2”.In "K2",there is a shapefile named "KCOUPL".

Answer (score 0):

There is an answer in the related GDAL bug report https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/issues/6472.

> The FileGDB SDK is quite restrictive on the CRS it accepts and it can
> be tricky to convince it. The best is to use the definition of an
> official EPSG code. DST_SRSWKT is not a valid options of
> https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/filegdb.html To override the CRS, you
> might rather use the GDALVectorTranslate() API (C API of ogr2ogr) with
> the -a_srs option.